# How to substract two DATES variables in R and outcome should be in days

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, cox-regression

I have following two columns in my data frame called `Entry_date`, `Death_date` containing dates in format of `YYYY/MM/DD`. I want to subtract like `(Death_date-Entry_date = survival_days)`. After subtracting `Death_date` from `Entry_date`, i want my outcome in days. My data looks like following.

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Entry_date<-c(2010/04/13, 2008/07/30, 2009/03/06, 2008/08/22, 2009/06/24, 2008/08/26)
Death_date<-c(2007/05/17, 2007/05/16, 2007/05/16, 2007/05/16,2007/05/16, 2010/05/16)
Df<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Entry_date,Death_date)
```

I want a column called Df$survival_days as outcome variable like following

```
Sample_ID  Entry_date       Death_date      Df$survival_days   
                                                -1062.00
                                                -441.00
                                                -660.00
                                                -464.00
                                                -770.00
                                                 468.00
```

How can i do this in R. I need this variable for my cox. regression survival analysis . My real data frame is having around 10,000 observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `difftime` with appropriate units and provide dates as strings:

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Entry_date<-c("2010/04/13", "2008/07/30", "2009/03/06", "2008/08/22", "2009/06/24", "2008/08/26")
Death_date<-c("2007/05/17", "2007/05/16", "2007/05/16", "2007/05/16","2007/05/16", "2010/05/16")
Df<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Entry_date,Death_date)
Df$difference_in_days <- difftime(Df$Death_date, Df$Entry_date, units = "days")
```

**Output**

```
> Df
  Sample_ID Entry_date Death_date difference_in_days
1        a1 2010/04/13 2007/05/17    -1062.0000 days
2        a2 2008/07/30 2007/05/16     -441.0000 days
3        a3 2009/03/06 2007/05/16     -660.0417 days
4        a4 2008/08/22 2007/05/16     -464.0000 days
5        a5 2009/06/24 2007/05/16     -770.0000 days
6        a6 2008/08/26 2010/05/16      628.0000 days
```

Comment: Thank you its helpful. But my real data has Dates pattern not as strings so is there any way in R or code by which i can change it into string variable first? p.s its a huge data

Comment: Sorry for being too dumb but i could not follow . Can you show me exact code for converting  my vector " Entry_date" into string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Aryh I think I don't follow too:). How is `Entry_data` stored in your data frame? Is it numeric?

Answer (score 2):

You can use difftime() with unit "days"

Comment: ... after first parsing the input to a `Date` object.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. That's how _I_ did it for 20+ years but I learned from the (now deservedly accepted answer) that `difftime()` even converts.  Neat.  (I'd still keep the data columns as `Date` objects but that is programming style...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lubridate` and `dplyr`. But first: I changed your input data:

```r
Sample_ID  <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Entry_date <- c("2010/04/13", "2008/07/30", "2009/03/06", "2008/08/22", "2009/06/24", "2008/08/26")
Death_date <- c("2007/05/17", "2007/05/16", "2007/05/16", "2007/05/16","2007/05/16", "2010/05/16")

Df <- data.frame(Sample_ID,Entry_date=ymd(Entry_date),Death_date=ymd(Death_date), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With this data

```r
Df %>%
  mutate(survival_days=Death_date - Entry_date)
```

yields

```r
  Sample_ID Entry_date Death_date survival_days
1        a1 2010-04-13 2007-05-17    -1062 days
2        a2 2008-07-30 2007-05-16     -441 days
3        a3 2009-03-06 2007-05-16     -660 days
4        a4 2008-08-22 2007-05-16     -464 days
5        a5 2009-06-24 2007-05-16     -770 days
6        a6 2008-08-26 2010-05-16      628 days
```

Comment: Sure, but no need for non-base-R packages. See the nice answer by @slava-kohut

Comment: You're right. Nevertheless OP didn't rule out non `base R` packages and `dplyr` gives great possibilitys for manipulating data, so why not showing them? :-)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel the `difftime()` answer is a very elegant way of getting the desired result, therefore I upvoted.